# Sort legend (for colorFactor) using leaflet package (RStudio) in Shiny App

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio, shiny

I'm deploying a shinyapp using the new leaflet package developed by RStudio. There doesn't appear to be much documentation online about some elements - in my case, I need to specify the order in which the legend displays the factor levels. Normally, I would do this (e.g. in ggplot2) by specifying the levels in advance of the plotting command as:

```
df$name <- factor(df$name, levels = sort(df$name))
```

However, this doesn't seem to work with the legend in leaflet. Below is a MWE (N.B. Africa geojson file can be downloaded [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27571064/africa.geo.json)). You will see that the legend order is not alphabetically sorted, as one would normally expect. My question is how one could do this.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

map_africa <- rgdal::readOGR("africa.geo.json", "OGRGeoJSON")

map_africa$name <- factor(map_africa$name, levels = sort(map_africa$name))

ui <- bootstrapPage( leafletOutput("map") )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  pal <- colorFactor('RdYlBu', map_africa$name)

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({ 

    leaflet(map_africa) %>% 
    addPolygons(stroke = F,
                fillColor = ~pal(name),
                popup = ~name) %>% 
    addLegend(position = 'topright',
              colors = ~pal(name), 
              labels = ~name) 

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try `labels = ~ sort(name)`, you might also want to sort the the names before creating the `pal` if you want the same colors

Comment: The function here is probably the best solution for now https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/256